# Is there a software to get mp3 rating from Spotify or iTunes

Tags: mp3, itunes, spotify

I'm broadcasting an internet radio and using Mixxx which allows priority of ratings of songs. Is there a software that gets rating in ID tag regarding Spotify, iTunes or somewhere else? I prefer free or open source if possible. It must run on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Maybe via the spotify API ....

Comment: Thanks for this nice help. It would be great if there was a simpler way.